# the Play/stop button is working properly. but background drawable is not working properly

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, android-view

[image: While playing second song]    i implemented play/stop button. when i press the same button while playing, it should be stop or pause && background also change play --> stop .when i press the another button while playing ,it should be stop and play the new song.it works.but couldn't change background play ---> stop. help me out.how to get the previous song id value...

```
         public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
protected static final String TAG = "MySImpleArrayAdapter";
private final Context context;
protected ListView mListView;
int itemno;
 Boolean playing = false;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
 String[] values;  
 int songs []=                   {R.raw.sound1,R.raw.sound2,R.raw.sound3,R.raw.sound4,R.raw.sound5,R.raw.sound6,R.raw.sound7};
  static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView text;
        public Button button;

      }

  public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, String[] values) {
    super(context, R.layout.activity_main, values);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.values = values;

  }


 @Override
  public View getView( int position, View rowView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (rowView == null) {

          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
          ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
          viewHolder.text = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
                  viewHolder.button = (Button) rowView
              .findViewById(R.id.logo);

          rowView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        String s = values[position];
      final int   pos=position;
        holder.text.setText(s);
        holder.button.setOnClickListener(
                new OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                         if(mp == null){

                              //  mListView.invalidateViews();
                                mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,songs[pos]);

                                mp.start();
                                playing = true;
                                itemno = pos;
                                //Toast.makeText(context, "ist playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ok);

                            }
                            else {
                                if(mp.isPlaying() && itemno == pos){

                                    mp.pause();
                                    playing = false;

                                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no);
                                }
                                else{
                                    if(playing == false  && itemno == pos){

                                        mp.start();
                                        playing = true;
                                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ok);
                                    }
                                    else {

                                        mp.stop();

                                        mp.release();
                                        mp = MediaPlayer.create(context,songs[pos]);
                                        mp.start();
                                        playing = true;
                                        itemno = pos;
                                        //Toast.makeText(context, "playing", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ok);

                                    }if (!mp.isPlaying())
                                        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.no);

                                }
                            }

                    }
                });






        return rowView;


      }

 @Override
 public boolean  areAllItemsEnabled() {
     return false;          
 }

 @Override
 public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
         return false;
 }
```

}

Comment: could you edit the question and frame it better? What do you mean by background? Do you the song's image at background wheen it is playing? Elaborate

Comment: what u exactly want??u want to play the song when press play and every time change the background when song changes??

Comment: Add images to tell what you exactly want...

Comment: @AnkitAggarwal i added now see,while playing second song...

Comment: @PankajSharma yea. i want something like that

Comment: lets she the below links it may help u..

Comment: plz atlest up vote my answer - @Divya Ramakrishnan

Comment: @DivyaRamakrishnan Did you solve this problem?! if you did, please shar this here, i've an issue like this

Answer (score 0):

http://www.brightec.co.uk/blog/custom-android-media-controller

http://www.verious.com/tutorial/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

hello this may help u...go through these links and find the solution.